# RMarkdown does not print chunk output inside RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I`ve started working on a new RMarkdown document. I've noticed that when running chunks inside RStudio, RStudio does not print their output (which it did before!) - neither "inline" below the code chunk nor to the console. This is a very annoying behaviour when working interactively. I've tried to fix it via the global options of RStudio and the chunk options with no success. Knitting the document works as expected.

Although, the problem is not about knitting the document here are the global chunk options I defined for the document.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  fig.align = 'center',
  dev = "svg",
  dpi = 500
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this option is chosen in your Code pane.

[image: RStudio GUI]

Comment: Does not work for me. Switching to "Chunk Output in Console" works, at least.